# Spring Data - Mongo DB - search

Tags: spring-data

I have this domain object

```
@Document(collection = "LabelsPredefined")
```

public class LabelsPredefined {

```
@TextIndexed
private String name;

public LabelsPredefined() {
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(final String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "[LabelsPredefined]";
}
}
```

and I have an input at frontend with autocomplete. Therefore I will start searching when user enters first char. This is my Spring data repository method:

```
@Query("{$text : { $search : ?0 } }")
Set<LabelsPredefined> findLabelsPredefinedBySearchString(final String searchString);
```

My problem is that only if whole search strings matches name than method responses the object. Is there any possible solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know this syntax:

`@Query("{$text : { $search : ?0 } }")`

Maybe you should try passing a TextCriteria instead of the string:

```
TextCriteria criteria = TextCriteria.forDefaultLanguage()
  .matchingAny(searchString);
```

And changing your signature method to:

```
Set<LabelsPredefined> findLabelsPredefinedBySearchString(TextCriteria criteria);
```